# Importing Site Specific Data to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I use https://www.soccerstats.com/formtable.asp?league=england to pull data into Google sheets using XML and then pull the data I need such as the last 4 at home, last 8 at home etc tables by using the cell references pulled through to tidy up on another sheet. The issue is that the site updates the format relatively consistently which means updated the references each time. Is there a way to pull the 'Last 4 at home table' so that it always simply comes through as it is on the site.

- no matter how the rest of the page is formatted? This would save an ungodly amount of time (even though I'm doing this purely for pleasure/gambling so y'know not the end of the world). Any help is magnificently appreciated.

I don't know how to pull the day past getting all of the page data.

Comment: whats your formula for `last8` and why its not working for you?

Comment: I dont have one for the tables specifically so I'm currently pulling all of the site data.